# Apache redirects all websites to one domain, if there is https

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a server where I have a lot of domains and one of them is ssl secured.

If I use any other domain with https:// it shows the content of the ssl secured site.

In my conf I use

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /home/domains/example.com/web/public/www/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/domains/example.com/web/ssl/www.example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/domains/example.com/web/ssl/www.example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/domains/example.com/web/ssl/www.example.com.ca
#   SSLCACertificateFile /home/domains/example.com/web/ssl/www.example.com.ca

    ErrorLog /home/domains/example.com/web/log/error.log
    CustomLog /home/domains/example.com/web/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

which I found may be the problem, but I did not find any way to solve it.

Can someone tell me how to solve it, or direct me to the appopriate documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: have you included the `ServerName` entry in this virtual host?

Comment: Yes, I did, I have there ServerName

Comment: please post the complete file(or more parts of it) as the above mentioned information is very less to find out the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of

> **ServerName inheritance**
>
> It is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in every name-based
>   virtual host. If a VirtualHost doesn't specify a ServerName, a server
>   name will be inherited from the base server configuration. If no
>   server name was specified globally, one is detected at startup through
>   reverse DNS resolution of the first listening address. In either case,
>   this inherited server name will influence name-based virtual host
>   resolution, so it is best to always explicitly list a ServerName in
>   every name-based virtual host.

[Soruce Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)

So try using this entry explicitly defining the ServerName Entry

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com 
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```